# How do I find my troposphere boundary? How will this affect my weather patterns?

Tags: science-based, physics, climate, atmosphere, weather

My world has a radius of .87 R<sub>Earth</sub>, an average temperature of 278 K, and an escape velocity of 9.3 km/s. My atmosphere is 1.81 atm at sea level and has a 14052 m scale height. Is this enough to figure out where my tropopause is?

Next, I'm wondering whether this will affect things like my mountains' rain shadows, formation of high-altitude lakes, average wind speeds in my trade winds, etc.

Comment: The tropopause is defined by the reversal of the vertical temperature gradient which separates the troposphere from the stratosphere. The reason the stratosphere is warmer is because of ozone photolysis. To get your tropopause height you need to find out at which height the maximum of ozone photolysis is happening.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so new to meteorology that I almost literally don't know which way is up ;p is there anywhere you'd recommend starting @Khris?

Comment: Problem is your numbers don't add up. Lets say your world has that smaller radius but has the same density as Earth, then your escape velocity would be 9.7 km/s and your gravitational acceleration would be 8.54 m/s². Unless your atmosphere's chemical composition is different you can't have a higher atmospheric pressure than on Earth because your gravitational pull is less. Your sea level pressure would be less than one Earth atmosphere. So I's recommend to check basic physics first to achieve consistency.

Comment: @Khris Why not? The pressure is a function of gravity **and** atmospheric mass. I am too lazy to do the math but he is providing a scale height higher than ours so he probably did do the math. (Why else would he even have that number?)

Comment: I was working on an answer to this, but I think you need to back up the bus one stop. In order to calculate the tropopause altitude, you need lapse rate. To calculate lapse rate of the atmosphere, you need $c_p$, the specific heat at a constant pressure. That can't be calculated, you have to get it off a chart for whatever gasses are in the air. So we need to know atmospheric composition. However, atmospheric composition will determine if your given pressure and scale height are correct, as @Khris points out. I think you should put this question on pause, and...

Comment: ...ask if your given pressure and scale height can work with whatever atmospheric composition you have chosen. Once that is done, we can get back to this question. I am actually going to recommend closing this question as 'unclear what you are asking' because there is not enough information to answer it, as given. We can always re-open it later with more information.

Comment: @Khris Atmospheric pressure is not a function solely of gravity and atmospheric composition. Just look at Venus: true, that atmosphere is mostly carbon dioxide rather than oxygen and nitrogen, but Venus has a weaker gravitational force. Carbon dioxide is heavier, true, but the pressure on Venus is around 90 times that of Earth; how, exactly, would you explain _that_ oversized gap?

Comment: @Palarran As kingledion has pointed out it's about atmospheric composition. Venus' atmosphere has a vastly different composition from Earth's atmosphere. Since OP has not provided this information I assumed an Earth atmosphere and starting calculations from there it doesn't work out.

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake when calculating gravitational acceleration, it can be directly calculated using radius and escape velocity, no need to make assumptions about the planetary density. However that leads to an even lower value of 7.8 m/s². Now lets say the atmosphere has a different composition from Earth, once you change the amount of oxygen it gets difficult because then you change the amount of UV-absorption and thus the tropopause height. And this is all still assuming the radiation comes from the sun or a star that has the same spectrum as the sun.

Comment: You can work this out out methodically. Planet size/avg density/surface gravity are interrelated (pick any 2 and you know the 3rd). Surface gravity/atmospheric content (or density)

Comment: You can work this out out methodically. Planet size/avg density/surface gravity are interrelated (pick any 2 and you know the 3rd). Surface gravity/atmospheric average content (proxy fordensity at ground level (and therefore its density at each other height) are interrelated - again pick any 2 and the 3rd will be known. The troposphere is where weather "stops" in a simple sense - by the time you have atmosphere density at different heights, and other factors like solar environment/magnetosphere details/atmosphere composition/volcanism/etc, you can make a good guess where the tropopause w

Comment: ...will be. (Sorry for slight ambiguity in my comment - the atmospheric content and heating/cooling factors affect heat and mass, both of which affect actual density profiles)